# Nginx, Express.js and Node on port 80

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I run my Express.js app on port 8000 and I want to work with localhost rather than localhost:8000 in my dev environment.

I'm on Mac OSX El Capitan and using nginx 1.8.0

I get `502 Bad Gateway` and `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error.

I stop nginx via `sudo pkill nginx` and start with `sudo nginx`. I also use `pm2` and start it via `sudo pm2 start bin/www --watch`, there's no problem here. I can access my app at localhost:8000

I installed nginx via homebrew.

/etc/hosts

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Here's my nginx.conf in /usr/local/etc/nginx

```
user  myusernameishere staff;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

sites-enabled/default.conf

```
server{
  listen 80;
  server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
  }
}
```

/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.default

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
    include servers/*;
}
```

Comment: I had a conflict with the server_name `localhost` , left it with 127.0.0.1 and it worked with no issues.

Comment: I see `Upgrade` and `Connection` headers in your nginx conf. Do you try to work with websockets?

Comment: I do work with websockets (socket.io), but it's not the main issue here. It turned out that MAMP's Apache also listens port 80. I uninstalled it and problem solved. After a few minutes, I installed MAMP again, started Apache but it didn't happen again, it's really weird. I don't know what to say at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your `sites_enabled/default.conf`:

```
upstream backend {
  server localhost:8000;
}

server{
  listen 80;
  server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
  }
}
```

Comment: It gives `nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "server_name" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf:3` error. Even if I correct it, I stil can't get localhost.

Comment: @salep - There was an error in the backend section of sites_enabled/default.conf above (corrected). I tried this on El Capitan w/nginx 1.8.0 installed view brew, which looks like your setup as well. The nginx part is working. If you're still getting 502's it is probably an issue with the application on port 8000.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade is a header from HTTP v1.1, you may need to include `proxy_http_version 1.1;` when using it.